# Number of integral solutions of $x_1.x_2.x_3=x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

Let $x$ be the element of the set $A=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,8,10,12,15,20,24,30,40,60,120\}$ and $x_1, x_2, x_3$ be positive integers and $d$ be number of integral solutions of $x_1.x_2.x_3=x$ , then $d$ is divisible by which of the following?

$(A)$ $10$

$(B)$ $15$

$(C)$ $20$

$(D)$ $25$

Could someone give me slight hint as how to approach this problem?

Comment: What if $x = 1$ ?

Comment: Are you requiring $x\in A$? It would make more sense to put $x=120$ and require $x_1,x_2,x_3\in A$.

Comment: @shailesh sir I think we need to check all numbers and the total sum of all such solutions is d and then the divisibility

Comment: @almagest That was what I was thinking about!